# Webapi - .Net restful put/update parameter convention on service/repo layers

Tags: c#, .net, rest, service, asp.net-web-api

I have a question about the standard way to perform a restful update.

We have a restful Api, with an update URL like the following :

```
put /jobs/{jobUid:guid}
```

The signature in the restful controller is:

```
UpdateJob(Guid jobUid, [FromBody] UpdateJobOperation job)
```

Our `UpdateJobOperation` class has all the same properties as our `Job` class except for the Id (Guid) is not in the `UpdateJobOperation` class.

Inside this update method, we map the `UpdateJobOperation` to our `Job` business object, then we call update on the service layer and pass in the job. The job object has a Guid Id property on it. So my question is the following :

should the signatures of our update on  the service layer and our update on repository layer (service will do business logic then call update on repository) be like:

```
UpdateJob(Job job)
```

OR

```
UpdateJob(Guid jobUid, Job job)
```

If we use single `Job` parameter, obviously we need to set the `JobUid` property on the `Job` before calling `UpdateJob` on the service.

Obviously both methods work but I have been unable to find if there is a best practice on service/repo updates.

What are your recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without risking a religious argument...

Strictly from a restful API point of view a PUT is for updating a resource that you have an id for. In this sense you API interface is fine. At your service layer I would be tempted to use the `Update(Job job)` signature as this can be re-used for you POST operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is correct. Especially, since if you were to get rid of the `jobUid` parameter you would end up with the end point `put /jobs` This could be mistook for an end point that updates multiple jobs as opposed to a single one.

Comment: I probably could have been a little more clear in my question. I am confident my put url / parmeters are correct. My real question is weather the update on service / repo layer should have 1 parameter or 2.

Comment: That should have a single parameter. There is no need to separate the jobUid from the job input class. If the id is part of the job domain, it should be included as part of the job class in the repo layer.